# stop location updates from the iphone UI?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, location, core-location

Is it possible to start / stop location updates from the UI of the iphone? All I need from the app is to show me my location unless I click "stop" and then "start" again.

I can't seem to be able to do that...I have my location displayed properly, and I also created two IBButtons and created a function for each of them, however, my app crashes when I click on each one of those buttons. I placed those functions under the viewcontroller.m.

I am kind of new to this, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

- (IBAction)startUpdating: (CLLocation *)location 
  {

  [location startUpdatingLocation];

  }
- (IBAction)stopUpdating: (CLLocation *)location
  {

  [location stopUpdatingLocation];

  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start/stopUpdatingLocation are `CLLocationManager` instance methods, rather than `CLLocation` instance methods... so create a `CLLocationManager` instance.

.h

```
@interface someClass:somesuperclass{
CLLocationManager * locationManager;
BOOL updating;
}
-(IBAction)toggleUpdating:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m somewhere in the view load/ or init cycle:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 }
 -(void)viewDidUnload{
 [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
 [locationManager release];
 [super viewDidUnload];
 }

-(IBAction)toggleUpdating:(id)sender
{
     if(!updating)
     {
         [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
     }else{
         [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
     }
     updating = !updating;
}
```

also your action above will never work, because the thing after a colon in an action will be the object that sent the action, a UIButton in your case.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful! Two quick questions though: 1. where should I put all this code? Is it ok to write it in the view controller? I put into the viewDidLoad method and it is not compiling...also: 2) how do I incorporate the start / stop UIBUttons with this implementation? I'd like to get user input with two buttons: start / stop. Thanks!

Comment: I changed to make a little more clear. You can use one button and change the name of the button based on `updating`, or split the logic into 2 actions. or set the tag of the UIButtons to 0, and 1, then check the sender.tag to see which button sent the action, you have a few options.

Comment: Thanks! So I ended up doing this  - (IBAction)startUpdating 
 {

     CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
     [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
 
 }
 
 
 
 - (IBAction)stopUpdating
 {
 
     CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
     [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
 
 }
With two IBButtons, but now when I click on Stop, it gets into this method, but I keep getting location updates on my console...does stopUpdatingLocation really stops or what am I missing here?

Comment: that is leaky and wont work, you need to only use one CLLocationManager, declare it in the .h file

Comment: I changed it all and did what you suggested precisely, however, stoping the updates still shows me location updates on the console...

Comment: do you get any compilation warnings?

Comment: I have some, but just for some unrelated unused variables...I saw on some other forums similar complains, but looks like they are really old, and do not contain any relevant solution anyway...kinda of a bummer.

Comment: you can set break points and make sure you aren't changing out the locationManager instance at some point. you need to alloc/init only one time.

Comment: ok you were right - I had another instance of CLLocationManager. Thanks for not giving up on me!